# ribbon custom action template in visual studio 12

Tags: visual-studio

I want to create a ribbon custom action for SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio 2012 but I am not finding where the Ribbon Action Control is. I can [see it here](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/12/11/creating-sharepoint-ribbon-custom-actions-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx) but I cannot see in my setup.

Comment: [That post](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/12/11/creating-sharepoint-ribbon-custom-actions-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx) clearly mentioned to start with App project to have that option: *First, you’ll need to create a new SharePoint App project*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Office Developer Tools to get these in your Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: None of these links working. Please update links.